# Computing square roots with arithmetic-harmonic mean

Tags: numerical-methods, radicals, means, newton-raphson

We know that if we iterate arithmetic and harmonic means of two numbers, we get their geometric mean.

So, basically if we need to compute the square root of $x$:

$$\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{1 \cdot x}=AHM(1,x)$$

$$a_0=1,~~~~b_0=x$$

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2},~~~~~b_{n+1}=\frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n}=\frac{a_nb_n}{a_{n+1}}$$

As far as I know, this expression will converge for any real positive $x$. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/678702/269624) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1192349/269624) question for example.

We can take other initial values, for example $x/2$ and $2$, but taking $1$ is enough in most cases.

I know, the idea is so simple, it's obvious. But I did not find this method anywhere among the methods for computing square roots.

It seems even better than Newton's method, because

- we do not need to think about initial values
- we do not need to check our result by squaring, we only need to check that $a_n-b_n=0$ with required precision.

---

Examples (here equality means that the provided number of digits is the same):

$$x=2:~~~~a_4=b_4=1.414213562$$

$$x=\frac{1}{3}:~~~~a_5=b_5=0.5773502692$$

$$x=\frac{1}{14}:~~~~a_6=b_6=0.2672612419$$

$$x=13:~~~~a_6=b_6=3.605551275$$

$$x=517:~~~~a_{9}=b_{9}=22.73763400$$

As you can see, even for numbers not close to $1$, the convergence is good.

And I did not even have to check if my values are correct - I only needed to look at $a_n$ and $b_n$ and see which digits are the same.

> Is this method used for computing roots along with Newton's method and others? If it is, could you provide a reference where it's discussed and compared to other methods? Will it always work in the way I described for any positive $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially the same as the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) for computing square roots, which is itself the same as Newton's method using the function $f(t) = t^2 -x$.  In particular, observe that
$$
a_{n+1}b_{n+1} \,=\, \biggl(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}\biggr)\biggl(\frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n}\biggr) \,=\, a_nb_n
$$
and hence $a_nb_n = a_0b_0 = x$ for all $n$.  Thus
$$
a_{n+1} \,=\, \frac{a_n+b_n}{2} \,=\, \frac{a_n + \dfrac{x}{a_n}}{2}.
$$

Comment: I see now. So this is exactly the same as if I started the iterations for Babylonian (Newton's) method with $1$ and used $a_n-x/a_n$ to check the number of correct digits. Thank you